# Python CV2 find.contours minimum dimensions

Tags: python, image-processing, ocr, opencv

I am using CV2 for hand writing segmentation and I am using the boundingRect function to bound the contours. The problem arises with symbols such as the "=" sign. Depending on how the equal sign is drawn, the function either bounds it as two separate "-" signs or as a single symbol. I tried checking for a minimum height for the boundingRect before making predictions, but this causes issues when the two dashes are drawn closely together and even when they are not, it will still sometimes separate the two. Is there a way to set a minimum height for findContours? Or even better, since my input is all one line, is there a way to prevent findContours from finding more than a single contour for a single vertical segment, meaning that if two symbols are one on top of the other, it won't take them as being seperate (like in the case ofi,j,=, etc)
This is part of my current code:

```
ctrs, hier = cv2.findContours(im_th.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
sorted_ctrs = sorted(ctrs, key=lambda ctr: cv2.boundingRect(ctr)[0])

for i, ctr in enumerate(sorted_ctrs):
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(ctr)
roi = im[y:y+h+20, x:x+w+20]
area = w*h

if 600< area: #Do stuff
```

Comment: What about using morphological closing to glob nearby things together? https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will take a look, but the documentation says that it's mostly useful for filling smaller holes within structures, do you think it would have an effect for something like "="?

Comment: Yes, it can be used for that. Check out the dilation example there---it expands the masks, which you can use on the equals signs to glob them together. Then, check out the erosion example---it thins something out. Closing is just doing dilation, then erosion. So what it will end up doing (with the right size kernels) is growing the equals sign until they merge together, and then reducing the exterior of that new blob down back to original size. But since they merge together in the process, they don't end up getting split up again. This works to fill small gaps, whether or not they are a "hole"

Comment: If you used the same input image they did with a slightly larger kernel for closing, it would merge the dot and the stroke of the j letter together.

Comment: Add a post processing step to group together contours that belong to the same character. For example `j` has a small blob that's above and pretty much centered above the big blob of the main letter. `=` are generally two similar blobs, one above each other (the bounding boxes have a significant overlap along the X axis).

Answer (score 0):

Morphological closing can be used to merge the two symbols together while retaining something with roughly the same external size as both. You can simply use a kernel size that matches the height difference you are expecting between the two pieces of the equals sign. This is often used on text for example to get single contours of characters that have multiple separate strokes or are broken by some thresholding operation, or equally, to merge all the characters of a single word together to get contours of each word individually.

The OpenCV [morphological transformations tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html) has some basic info on how this works. As an example, we'll use their starting image and use morphological closing to get a contour that includes both the dot and the stroke of the lowercase letter "j":

[image: Binarized letter j]

Now using a large enough kernel for closing, we get:

```py
kernel = np.ones((7, 7), np.uint8)
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
```

[image: Morphologically closed j]

Now of course this isn't exactly the same as what we started with, you'll notice the inner angles of the "j" have been filled a bit as well. This can be somewhat avoided; you can get the contours of each piece of the character *before* the operation, and then only select the part of the mask that joined two separate contours. However that probably won't be necessary for most tasks and certainly not for your equals sign, so I'll ignore that.

Now you can just get the contours as usual on this closed image, and mask your original image from that:

```py
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(closing, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
bgr_img = cv2.merge([img, img, img])
contour_img = cv2.drawContours(bgr_img, contours, -1, (255, 0, 255))
```

[image: Single contour over the separated character]

And you can find your bounding boxes or minimum bounding rectangles with these contours instead.